# Summation involving product of hypergeometric functions

Tags: summation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, hermite-polynomials

I started with the following sums involving the product of Hermite polynomials.

> $f(x,y;u)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2m}(x) H_{2m}(y)}{(2m)!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^{2m} \tag{1}$

> $g(x,y;u)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2m+1}(x) H_{2m+1}(y)}{(2m+1)!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^{2m+1} \tag{2}$

where $u$ is a constant.

Using the [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Relations_to_other_functions) of the Hermite polynomials, $H_n(x)$, to the Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function, $ {}_1 F_1(a;b;x)$, for even and odd $n$, I rewrite the sums $(1)$ and $(2)$ as follows.

> $f(x,y;u)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{{}_1 F_1(-m;\frac{1}{2};x^2){}_1 F_1(-m;\frac{1}{2};y^2)}{m!} \big(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^{2m} \tag{3}$

> $g(x,y;u)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{4xy{}_1 F_1(-m;\frac{3}{2};x^2){}_1 F_1(-m;\frac{3}{2};y^2)(2m+1)!}{(m!)^2} \big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^{2m+1} \tag{4}$

I'm wondering how to compute the sums $(3)$ and $(4)$ involving the product of hypergeometric functions. Any ideas on this would be much appreciated.

Addendum: I understand that the sum analogous to $(3)$ involving the Hermite polynomials i.e., $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_{m}(x) H_{m}(y)}{m!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^{m}$ has a closed-form expression given by the [Mehler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation). Therefore, in this context, is there also a closed-form expression for the sum $(3)$ and possibly, $(4)$?

Comment: $$H_{2m}(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int (-1)^m s^{2m} e^{isx-s^2/4}\,ds $$
gives
$$ f(x,y,u)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{H_{2m}(x)H_{2m}(y)}{(2m)!}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^{2m}=\frac{e^{x^2+y^2}}{4\pi}\iint\left(\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(ust)^{2m}}{2^{2m}(2m)!}\right)e^{isx+ity-s^2/4-t^2/4}\,ds\,dt $$
which equals
$$ \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}}{4\pi}\iint\cosh\left(\frac{ust}{2}\right)e^{isx+ity-s^2/4-t^2/4}\,ds\,dt $$
It is enough to mimic the last lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you! This solved the problem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm also interested in evaluating the following sum. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509703/suggestions-to-evaluate-a-summation-involving-hermite-polynomials. I have asked it as a separate question where I have shown my approach in detail. Could you please take a look at it?